# Adding root identifier to JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have a controller which returns my SalesOrder DTO as JSON as follows:

```json
{
    "SalesOrderId": 19550,
    "OrderNumber": "1625-002-19550"
}
```

I need to return it as such:

```json
{
    "SalesOrder": [
        {
            "SalesOrderId": 19550,
            "OrderNumber": "1625-002-19550"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Controller:

```cs
public class SalesOrderController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    [Route("[action]/{id}/")]
    public async Task<Object> GetSalesOrderReport(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return Json(await SalesOrderService.GetSalesOrderReport(id));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { code = "422", success = false, message = "Unable to fetch sales orders - " + ex.ToString() });
        }
    }
}
```

My service returns a `SalesOrder` DTO.

```cs
public class SalesOrderViewModel
{
    public int SalesOrderId { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Can I do this using Annotations or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: The easiest thing would be to accept it as a single object then add it to a List or array yourself.

Comment: Why do you use `Task<Object>`? Why don't you use `Task<IActionResult>`?

Comment: Thank you for spotting that, Peter. I have changed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the model which will give you the output type you are asking for.

```
public class SalesOrderRoot 
{
     public List<SalesOrderViewModel> SalesOrders {get; set;}
}
```

or you can do

```
return Json(new { SalesOrder = new List<SalesOrderViewModel>
{ 
  (await SalesOrderService.GetSalesOrderReport(id))
}
```

Comment: Or simply just: `new { SalesOrder = new [] { report }}`